# Probability that first failure is on $i^{th}$ day?

Tags: probability

Suppose that you have two different types of pumps with different probabilities of failure on any particular day. Let these probabilities be $p_1$
and $p_2$ . What is the probability that the first failure is on the $\large i^{th}$ day?

Assume that the chance of failure does not depend on the number of days
that a pump is in use.

> Iam trying to solve above problem by using inclusion-exclusion principle. Let A = $p_1$ fails on $i^{th}$ day and $B = p_2$ fails on $i^{th}$ day. Then iam trying to find $P(A \cup B)$.
>
> $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$

$P(A) = (1-p_1) + (1 - p_1)^2 + \dots + (1-p_1)^{i-1}p_1$ and  then finding $P(B)$, $P(A \cap B)$ and substituting above.

But I cannot satisfy myself that it is the right way to go for this problem. Please help me understand this.

Comment: Are the probabilities the pumps fail independent?

Comment: Although nothing is mentioned in problem statement, but lets assume they are independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.   That's got the right idea, but not the right application.

You are given the probabilities for failure on any particular day are $p_1,p_2$ for each pump.   These shall be assumed to have independence on any given day.

So the probability for failure of either pump on any particular day is: $p_1+p_2-p_1p_2$, by your inclusion/exclusion formula.

Now you just want to find the probability for $i-1$ consecutive days with no failure followed by the first failure on day $i$.

> $$(1-p_1-p_2+p_1p_2)^{i-1}\cdot(p_1+p_2-p_1p_2)$$

Comment: Graham you applied inclusion exclusion on each day probability and then brought them together.. i understand. But can you point out Which probability will i get using my approach earlier ?

Comment: You were trying to evaluate the probability that one of the pumps fails for the first time on day $i$. $~$ You were neglecting cases where the first failure of one pump was on the right day but the other pump had failed earlier. @mcjoshi

Comment: Please explain :: (You were neglecting cases where the first failure of one pump was on the right day but the other pump had failed earlier) bit more.

Comment: Exaclty as said. The event $A$ of "pump 1 fails for the first time on day $i$" does not account for what day pump 2 might fail. @mcjoshi

Comment: I understand now @Graham

Answer (score 1):

Count the days as 1, 2, 3... (starts from 1)

Pump 1 failed on and not before the $i^{th}$ day: $(1-p_{1})^{i-1}p_{1}$

Pump 2 not fail on and before $i^{th}$ day $(1-p_{2})^{i}$

"And" of the above two cases (as they are independent): 
$(1-p_{1})^{i-1}p_{1}(1-p_{2})^{i} $

"Or" of the above and the above case with $p_1$ and $p_2$ switched:

$(1-p_{1})^{i-1}p_{1}(1-p_{2})^{i} + (1-p_{2})^{i-1}p_{2}(1-p_{1})^{i}$

Add a term for pump1 and pump 2 both failed on but not before the $i^{th}$ day...

$(1-p_{1})^{i-1}p_{1}(1-p_{2})^{i} + (1-p_{2})^{i-1}p_{2}(1-p_{1})^{i} + (1 - p_{1})^{i-1}p_{1}(1 - p_{2})^{i-1}p_{2}$

That is (A failed and B not failed) or (A not failed and B failed) or (A failed and B failed) on but not before the $i^{th}$ day.

Comment: You did it like A (or) B. A fails or B fails, which also includes the case when both of them fail. Liked this approach too.

Comment: Graham Kemp's solution is cleaner particularly if we let $q = p_{1} + p_{2} -p_{1}p_{2}$ Mine is a no brainer because I am lazy and tired. :D

Comment: I should cut and paste this onto my friend's exam and ask him to give an explanation of the last equation without showing the derivation.

Comment: I doubt whether your last term is right. It should be $(1-p_1)^{i-1}p_1 (1-p_2)^{i-1}p_2$

Comment: By "You were neglecting...", Graham means if A failed on day 3, the probability that B would fail on day 4, 5, 6... doesn't matter. So, you can't evaluate the probability for just one of A or B and then combine them later by "or" in that way.

Comment: Oh yeah right.. Thanks (...)